# Is finding the factorial of 5000 possible in javascript

Tags: javascript, factorial

I want to find the factorial of 5000 but once I try to pass 100 it'll return infinity. Is there are way to bypass this and get the result? I am trying to get the time it takes to solve this.

```
function testSpeed(n) {
    if (n > 0 && n <= 1) {
         return 1;
    } else {
         return n * testSpeed(n-1);
    }
}
console.log(testSpeed(5000));
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: You should share the code that gets you here:  *but once I try to pass 100 it'll return infinity*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've noticed, Javascript numbers can only get so big before they just become "Infinity". If you want to support bigger numbers, you'll have to use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt).

Examples:

```js
// Without BigInt
console.log(100 ** 1000) // Infinity

// With BigInt
// (stackOverflow doesn't seem to print the result,
// unless I turn it into a string first)
console.log(String(100n ** 1000n)) // A really big number
```

So, for your specific bit of code, all you need to do is turn your numeric literals into BigInt literals, like this:

```js
function testSpeed(n) {
  if (n > 0n && n <= 1n) {
      return 1n;
  } else {
      return n * testSpeed(n-1n);
  }
}

console.log(String(testSpeed(5000n)));
```

You'll find that youe computer can run that piece of code in a snap.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to give the correct result (according to https://coolconversion.com/math/factorial/What-is-the-factorial-of_5000_%3F)

```js
const longFactorial = (num) => {
   let result = num;
   for (let i = 1n; i < num; i++) {
      result = result * (num - i)
   }
   return String(result);
}
console.log(longFactorial(5000n));
```

Answer (score 0):

I can receive for 170! maximum:

```
function factorial (y){
    if (y ==0 || y ==1){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        f = y - 1;
        while (f >= 1) {
            y = y * f;
            f--;
        }
        return y;
    }
}
console.log(factorial(170));
```